# "Unhandled Exception: Unable to Configure HTTPS Endpoint in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, kestrel-http-server

Hi I'll explain briefly what I'm trying to do. 
 So basically I have a blazor project which I published and placed it in a folder, this project is not hosted in IIS because the project runs some processes in the server so what I do I run the .exe to run it as a kestrel. So I was tasked to make a Windows Service so the kestrel can run automatically every time the server boots up or restarts but I'm having a problem.

**THE PROBLEM:** 
I created the service using this command

> sc create <SERVICE_NAME> binPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXXX\XXXXX.exe"

As you can see its pointing to the .exe, but when I try to run the service I get this error in the event viewer

> Application: XXXXX.exe
> CoreCLR Version: 6.0.2123.36311
> .NET Version: 6.0.21
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
> To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
> For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in D:\XXXXX\XXXXX\source\repos\XXXXX\XXXXX\Program.cs:line 55

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**
I ran these commands but I'm still getting the same error.
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust

I have my kestrel endpoints in my
[appsettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBPx4.png)

and this is my program.cs

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions()
{
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default,
    Args = args
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.TryAddTransient<IExcelReader, ExcelReader>();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IXMLService, XMLService>();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<ICommandPromptService, CommandPromptService>();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IGRLoaderService, GRLoaderService>();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

I dont know what else to do.

**NOTE:**
Funny thing is that when I run it normal (not as service) it works perfectly.

Comment: [Please check this official document, and using the self-signed certificate.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-windows-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi so after a lot of research and no results I've finally found the solution to this problem.

First I specified which name is going to use when the service name is specified:

```
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "hereGoesYourServiceName";
});
```

What this does is basically when we create the windows service with the specified name our app is going to identify that service in the system.

Second I made a tiny change to my kestrel in my appsettings.json (you can see my old Kestrel settings [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBPx4.png)) so now it looks like this:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://path:port"
    },
    "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
      "Url": "https://path:port",
      "Certificate": {
        "Path": "pathToCert",
        "Password": "yourPwd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Third I added this line of code to my Program.cs

```
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.Configure(context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"))
    .Endpoint("HTTPS", listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.HttpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    });
});
```

So this specifies what endpoint the app is going to use.

Fourth I added this last line of code (at the top of Program.cs)

```
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions() 
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory,
    ApplicationName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
};
```

After that I proceeded to publish my app in the server and then generated a self-signed certificate (it is highly recommended to use a CA trusted certificate otherwise when deploying the app to production it will generate a warning telling you the site is not trusted) and then created the service in the server.

For further details you can use this answer as reference:

[Getting Blazor WebAssembly Server running as a Windows Service using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76560699/getting-blazor-webassembly-server-running-as-a-windows-service-using-https)